# Flask server not visible local network

Tags: python, flask, webserver

I'm trying to get the server that comes with Flask to run inside my network but I can't get it to work properly, it simply doesn't load.

For test purposes I'm running a simple hello world app using `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')` and it loads fine from the host but I get a timeout when connecting from another machine.

I tried forcing other ports using `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='80')` but I had no success. Using the IP explicitly like `app.run(host='10.X.X.X')` didn't help either.

However I don't think it is a network problem since I can successfully do a `ping 10.X.X.X` from the second machine and get the response.

**The question: Can it maybe have anything to do with the IP being in the format "10.X.X.X"? What else can be causing this behavior?**

Comment: How is the machine you're running the app on configured? Does the firewall allow incoming connections to port 80?

Comment: I'm not really sure actually, it is a corporative network and I don't really know much about it or the how the computers are configured.
I tried others ports like 5000 and 8050 as well but it didn't work.

Is there a way to check the ports without having admin rights?